# Why can't I find a small vacuum fryer?

Tags: pressure, pressure-vessel, vacuum-pumps

I'm looking for a vacuum fryer and so far the only ones available to buy are large, industrial machines.
Is there some technical consideration that makes small scale machines economically unfeasible?

This guy makes his own from a pressure cooker and a pump:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oSJ3b3KwGU&t=2s

Is a small vacuum fryer for home use feasible? How would the condenser work without using dry ice?

Comment: Cost and size of market com to mind...

Comment: Alibaba has them for $500

Comment: The vacuum pump would need some good filtering, filters would be full of grease in no time . . .   Still, considering the popularity of the [air fryer](https://www.ninjakitchen.com/exclusive-offer/AF161WBKT/ninja-air-fryer-max-xl/) it wouldn't surprise me if this follows. Cool video tho. The dry ice is just showing off